# instagram api. Как получить список подписчиков пользователя?

Tags: c#, instagram

Используя апи инстаграма пытаюсь получить список подписчиков пользователя, токен считывается правильно, пытаюсь считать вот так, но выдаёт ошибку 400(ошибка на стороне клиента). Использую библиотеку xNet. Вот код:

```
public string tok = Gettoken();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText("tokken.txt", followby());
    //MessageBox.Show(Gettoken());
}

public static string Gettoken()
{
    string clientID = "**********************";
    string clientSecret = "****************";
    string redirect_uri = "https://localhost";

    var info = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&response_type=token";

    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(string.Format(info));

    string str = response.ToString();
    string pattern = @"([0-9a-f]{32})";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(str);
    return match.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
}

string followby()
{
    var info = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/23423443/follows?access_token=" + tok;

    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
    HttpResponse response = request.Get(string.Format(info));//тут ошибку выдаёт

    return response.ToString();
}
```

Кто работал уже с этим, подскажите, как считать людей, подписанных на пользователя?

Comment: Возможно, [это поможет.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932205/how-i-can-get-the-number-of-followers-from-a-instagram-profile-using-aspx-net-c)

Answer (score 1):

Я рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, тем самым не тратить время на то, что уже давно за вас сделано. Воспользуйтесь [InstaSharp](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp).

[Тут](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/blob/master/src/InstaSharp/Endpoints/Subscription.cs#L218) реализовано получение подписчиков.

Использовать так:

```
InstagramWebHookClient client = Dependencies.Client;
var lst = client.ListAllSubscriptions();
```

[Тут](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/tree/master/src/InstaSharp.Sample.Mvc) ASP MVC пример с использованием `InstaSharp`'a

Данный фреймворк можно подключить через NuGet командой:

```
Install-Package InstaSharp
```

Comment: там очень запутано всё реализовано, я не знаю как это реализовать программно. у Вас случаем нет примера?

Comment: @inkorpus  я вам дал ссылку на гитхаб, там представлены исходники фреймворка, код написан вполне хорошо, комментарии есть, в чем проблема воспользоваться?

Comment: ну вот, я использую последний метод, который там показан. http://cs627224.vk.me/v627224952/893c7/FauPUTOwN6c.jpg где взять эти 2 элемента?

Comment: А кто клиент за вас создавать будет?

Comment: http://cs627224.vk.me/v627224952/893d1/wwtgY7ZhdLM.jpg я и спрашиваю, как его создать?

Comment: какой using подключить?

Comment: InstaSharp.Endpoints

Comment: подключил, но ничего не изменилось. в методе с гитхаба может как-то отдельно клиент создать надо сначала?

Comment: Вы сам инсташарп подключили?

Comment: разумеется!) using InstaSharp; скачана последняя версия с NuGet

Comment: у Вас проектом закинуть для примера не получится?

Comment: @inkorpus на гитхабе я вам дал ссылку на готовый проект, с примером использования большинства функций, чем он вас не устраивает?

Comment: ну наверно потому что мне нужен именно пример того, как вывести список подписчиков себе в текстовый файл, а там замудрено всё настолько, что я, как начинающий в программном  деле не понимаю как воспользоваться этим методом??